# Why can't I take pictures using the timer of my Nikon D5200?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d5200, self-timer

When I try to take a picture using the timer, sometimes the indicator doesn't blink so I have to click the shutter a couple of times for it to start counting. Why is that? I'm using a Nikon D5200 with the 18-55mm lens kit.

Comment: Are you waiting for it to get a focus lock before fully depressing the shutter? I am fairly sure you need to pre-focus (ie it doesnt autofocus just before taking the shot)

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft That must be it, I think. Thank you. I'm fairly new to photography, does it mean I should just keep pressing it until I get a focus lock? Don't I have to do anything else?

Comment: no, you need to HALF-depress the shutter, it will focus, then you fully depress to start the timer, EXACTLY as you should be doing to take any normal shot.

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft okay thank you so much. Will try it later as soon as I get home.

Comment: no problems, I have made an answer below, please mark it as correct if it solves your problem :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are not waiting for the camera to get a focus lock before fully depressing the shutter - as per taking normal photos you need to HALF-depress the shutter, wait for focus (at your desired point) and then fully depress to start the timer.

If you are struggling to find a focus point at your desired distance, you could always use manual focus mode instead.